# Is there a way to show Checkbox preferences and preference header in the same preference activity?

Tags: android, android-settings

I have a preference header file, which has a list of subscreens. Now I want to add couple of Checkbox preference in the same screen.

```
<preference-headers xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<header
    android:fragment="GeneralSettingsFragment"
    android:title="@string/settings_general" />
<header
    android:fragment="GeneralSettingsFragment"
    android:title="@string/settings_general" />
.
.
```

I want to have two of this in the same screen:

```
<CheckBoxPreference
    android:defaultValue="true"
    android:key="cb_drawertabs"
    android:title="@string/tabs_in_drawer" />
```

I cannot add a preference screen/ preference category/ checkbox preference inside a preference header. Is there any way around?